# Azure Data Factory - handling lookup activity limitation of 4194304 in size

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I have a azure data factory pipeline with a lookup activity that check a JSON file.

The size is like below in azure:
[Azure Blog Size Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VznGB.png)

and when I download it, I see below values for the file. so it's not larger that the value the error states: "The size 5012186 of lookup activity result exceeds the limitation 4194304"

[Size of the data as opened in Notepad ++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAMtF.png)

Also below is the design of my pipeline that gets stuck:
[Pipeline design - Lookup Activity to Read my model.json file to retrieve metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSfn0.png)

Any ideas on how to tackle this issue? thanks in advance

Comment: approximately how many rows dose contained in your source data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As lookup has the limitation of 5000 rows, you can try the below workaround for this.

To overcome this the workaround is as mentioned in [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity)

> **Design a two-level pipeline where the outer pipeline iterates over an inner pipeline, which retrieves data that doesn't exceed the maximum rows or size.**

**Possible solution:**

First, try to save your files list as JSON files to a folder of Blob storage with the size of 5000 rows.

**create Get Metadata activity which can fetch the files from the folder**

Get Metadata activity settings
[image]

**Then create For-each activity to Iterate over files**

In for-each activity setting give **items** as `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`
[image]

For the files create a dataset and give the folder name manually and for filename use the dataset parameter, which we can give the filename in the lookup inside the parent ForEach.

[image]

Lookup activity inside Parent ForEach give the file name as   `@string(item().name)`

[image]

**Execute Pipeline activity:**

Before this create an  **array parameter**  in the child pipeline and pass the look up output inside ForEach to that in the Execute Pipeline activity.
[image]

Give look up output  `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`

[image]

Now create inside the Child Pipeline and give the array parameter to the ForEach as  `@pipeline().parameters.ok`
[image]

You can use which ever activity you want inside this ForEach, here I have used append.
[image]

Then create **result1** variable as `array` and give value as `@variables('arrayid')`
[image]

**The Output will be the array of all ids in the file**

[image]BgULa02.png)

Comment: It does look like you found to make it work. Isn't it unfortunate that such a pointless limit requires such a complex workaround? I'd really like to know what Microsoft's justification is for limiting to 5,000 items.