# Azure Data Factory - How do I iterate and read records in a CSV file using a ForEach loop?

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-factory, lookup

I have a requirement to generate a unique 'guid' for each row in the dataverse, and for that, I'm using an additional column in the copy activity as shown below.

[image: Image 1 Description]

Since it generates the same guid for every row, I'm trying to use a lookup and iterate through a "For Each" loop as shown below.

[image: Image 2 Description]

In the "For Each" loop, I'm using this expression to retrieve the values:

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value
```

However, I'm encountering this error:

[image: Image 3 Description]

This is a sample output from the lookup activity: I'm using .csv file as the source

```json
{
    "firstRow": {
        "Bill-to Customer Name": "****",
        "Bill-to Customer No_": "****",
        // ... (other fields)
        "ProjectCustomer_FullName": "****",
        "ProjectCustomer_ID": "****"
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "****",
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "****",
        // ... (other billing reference fields)
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": ****
    }
}
```

How to resolve this issue ? Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Where’s the data coming from?  Where’s it going to?

Comment: Data is coming from a .csv file in a blob and will be passed to Dynamics 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate the CSV file using ForEach, you need to Disable the **`First row only`** in the lookup. I got same error, when I used expression `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` in the ForEach without disabling the **`First row only`** in the lookup.

[image]

Because, `First row only` will give the First row of csv as the object.

Disabling it will give the Lookup output array from the csv and you can see My pipeline ran without any errors after disabling it.

[image]

Use the same `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` in the ForEach to use the lookup output array. Inside ForEach, you can access this array values by `@item().<property_name>` or `@item()['<property_name>']`.

Comment: My source file contains more than 5000 rows; because of this, I cannot uncheck the first row. Only then, the lookup activity can read the whole file.

Comment: But, if you don't uncheck it, it won't give you the output array which you wanted to pass to the foreach activity. What you want to pass to the Foreach here, only firstRow?

Comment: To iterate the csv file which has more than 5000 rows, first split the file into less rows files using dataflow partitions and store it in a temporary folder. Then use this method to save the output array from all files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74120807/azure-data-factory-handling-lookup-activity-limitation-of-4194304-in-size

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try
@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.ProjectCustomer_ID

Comment: Got this error 

The execution of template action 'MainForEach1' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.ProjectCustomer_ID' is of type 'String'. The result must be a valid array.